# Dynamic change .click value Jquery IE issue

Tags: jquery, dynamic, internet-explorer, onclick

it's i first time i'm asking here. Sorry if the answer is available already.

I have a very small jQuery script that canges the paramether for onclick attr on a DIV.

IT works like as right and left arrows for some content in the middle.

Basically i set the `onclick="foo(1)"` then when get clicked sld change the value 1 to 2, and keep changing everytime i click.

on jQuery functio i'm using:

```
$("#v_arrow_r").attr('onclick','').unbind().click(newclick_next);
```

it works like a charm on FF and Chrome, but does not work on IE !!!! Argh...

here the the code:

```
if (start == 24) {
 var a = 0;
 var b = 0;
} else {
 var a = start-6;
 var b = start+6;
}

next = "home_featured_videos(" + b + ");"; 
newclick_next = eval("(function(){"+next+"});");

prev = "home_featured_videos(" + a + ");";
newclick_prev = eval("(function(){"+prev+"});");

$('#video-module').css('background','');
$('#video-module').html(response);

$("#v_arrow_l").attr('onclick','').unbind().click(newclick_prev);
$("#v_arrow_r").attr('onclick','').unbind().click(newclick_next);
```

The html:

```
<div id="videos-home">
  <div class="arrow-l" id="v_arrow_l" onclick="home_featured_videos(0);"></div>
  <div class="content" id="video-module">
   //CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-r" id="v_arrow_r" onclick="home_featured_videos(6);"></div>
  <div class="clear_b"></div>
</div>
```

So like i said.. i define the attr onclick when page open. It work well on IE. but when i click the arrow and call the function the oncli is set to null and i add the function to .click. IE stop working. the click is dead.

If anybody have idea why this is happening.

Thanx in advance.
Kind Regards

Varois

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#v_arrow_r").attr('onclick','').
```

Don't use `attr` to set event handler attributes. It doesn't work in IE and it's ugly and inefficient everywhere. If you're using jQuery, use the methods jQuery gives you for event binding, such as `click()`.

Inline event handler attributes are an old-school hack you should generally avoid anyway.

```
next = "home_featured_videos(" + b + ");"; 
newclick_next = eval("(function(){"+next+"});");
```

You should almost never use `eval`, and you certainly don't want to assign a new handler function every time there's a click. Store the current state in a variable and read it from the handler. For example:

```
<div id="videos-home">
    <div class="arrow-l" id="v_arrow_l""></div>
    <div class="content" id="video-module">
        //CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-r" id="v_arrow_r"></div>
    <div class="clear_b"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var pagei= 0; // initial page number
    var pagen= 4; // 4 pages (of 6 items each)

    $('#v_arrow_l').click(function() {
        turnpage(-1);
    });
    $('#v_arrow_r').click(function() {
        turnpage(1);
    });

    function turnpage(d) {
        pagei= (pagei+pagen+d)%pagen;
        $('#video-module').css('background','');
        $('#video-module').html('Page '+pagei); // or load() some AJAX or whatever
    }

</script>
```